# Making ID as default search in Solr

Tags: search, solr, indexing, unique

I am **novice** in **Solr**. I want to build a **documents** just like below.

```
{
  id : "what"
  count : "123"
},
{
  id : "what is"
  count : "134"
}
```

Here. I used **id** as **term(string)** which will be unique values. If I do indexing and searching on id. Will it reduce the speed* of searching in Solr or it is not a better way to make id as default search. Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not have any real impact - as long as the field is actually defined as a StrField. 
You should not have a unique id field that is defined as a TextField and where there are several filters and tokenizers applied.

Whether it's the default search field or not does not matter performance wise, just what field `q=what is` will be matched against.